# Apache Testing-Port/socket issue

Tags: linux, apache, binding, ports

Ok so I'm using Linux and I have configured Apache,APR,APR-util, and I went to test Apache via
((usr/sbin/apachectl start)) & this comes up:

[

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

no listening sockets available, shutting down

Unable to open logs

]

From the research Ive done the first warning can be safely ignored and to edit the listening sockets you edit the http.conf file to include : Listen [port#], but no matter what I put the SAME thing comes up about port 80.

Ive tried Listen 90,Listen 9540, Listen with the ip address and port # and nothing changes the message

Any ways to fix this?

Comment: are you starting the server as root? You need administrator/root privileges to bind to any port less than port 1024.

Comment: The thing is ive edited the httpd.conf file to Listen 8439 and it still says "could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 but nothing the the conf file tells it to do that